# Error occurs while install Oracle BIEE

Tags: windows, oracle, obiee

I'm trying to install Oracle BIEE 11g on my computer, but something wiered happend.
I've tried on a x86 computer with 2GB memory and a x64 computer with 4GB memory. Both of them are running Windows OS. I want to connect a MS-SQLSERVER database, and I've finished creating related DEV_ tables using RCU.

I followed the tutorial from the doc.oracle.com, but then I stopped at the 14th step, it says "设置数据库连接失败". I can continue install, but another error occurs, service obisch1 cannot start. I can open localhost:9704 after installation, but it will return a 500-error after I restart my computer.

I searched the internet, it says I should set my database source using "Net Manager" Tool, but I don't know how. And after install I got a database source using driver "MERANT OEM 5.3 32-BIT SQL Server Wired Protocol", but I can't make change to it, cause the system says can't find the driver...

I don't know what to do now... Anybody can help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've kind of solved it.

I still don't know why my computer cannot find the odbc drier "MERANT OEM 5.3 32-BIT SQL Server Wired Protocol", which seems to be the reason why I can't connect to the database at the 14th step while I install OBIEE.

However, I add an odbc-connect through the system's function, I found it in the control panel.
On the other hand, the url `http://localhost:7001/em` and `http://localhost:7001/analytics` can be still accessed(after a long time, it can be accessed).

So, then I create a rpd file use my own odbc-connect, and it seems work fine.

Thanks everybody, anyway, and hopes can help